# Trying to make star-rating control remember the rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is an example of rating "control" I found here http://jsfiddle.net/RpfLa/400/ It works fine but it doesn't have the ability to keep the star highlighted when it was clicked.

Although to make it work I just have to add `class="rated"` to a tag(s) `s` but it's still a bit complicated.

```
 <!-- a rating with 1 star -->
    <span class='star-rating'>
      <s class='rated'>
       <s>
        <s>
         <s>
          <s>
          </s>
         </s>
        </s>
       </s>
      </s>
     </span>
```

I just can't figure out what the efficient algorithm for that.

So when I know what the rating is

```
var numStars = $(e.target).parentsUntil("span").length+1;
```

How do I find a relevant `s` and make it and all ones before it have `class="rated"`?

Comment: `<s>` isn't valid HTML. You shouldn't do this, even if it does render correctly. You should use a `span` or `div` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/RpfLa/472/)

```
$(function() {
    $("div.star-rating > s, div.star-rating-rtl > s").on("click", function(e) {
        $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").andSelf()
        .addClass('rated').end().end()
        .find('.rated').removeClass('rated');
    });
});
```

Relevant links: [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf), [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end), [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)

Most of these are intuitively named. `andSelf` adds the current element to the matched set after using a filter like `parentsUntil`. `end` cancels that filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Can you select the top element and just loop down through all of the stars? Something like:

```
starSpan = $(".star-rating"); //or whatever selector you want to use for the span
currentStar = starSpan
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    currentStar = currentStar.children('s :first')
    if (i <= numStars) {currentStar.attr('class','rated')}
    else {currentStar.attr('class','')}
}
```

That way you can deal with reducing the star ratings as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(e.target).parent('div').find('.rated').removeClass('rated');
$(e.target).addClass('rated');
$(e.target).parentsUntil("div").addClass('rated');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KczMC/